# How to test cache in Android/IOS Mobile application?

Tags: manual-testing

We have a mobile application(Native), few days back we have implemented cache in the application. Now i am not sure how to test it, i can see it storing and taking memory in the settings section.

But is this cache being used again by my application, how to test it?

Comment: what do you mean by cache ?

Comment: cache is a application component that stores data, so future requests for that data can be served faster

Comment: You should talk to the developers who implemented it then, how can we know the implementation details ?

Comment: @Rsf : it's implemented in same way for all applications, we are not developing a different thing. cache and cookies are universal thing and tested same way. That's why i was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Android**

Use DDMS at android developer studio or eclipse (you have to download the ADT plugin for this if you are with eclipse).

Inside the DDMS you can monitor cache memory, GC, Threads and more things of an android application.

And you can also dump the memory of the android application and you can do a inspection/go through on the dump and analyze the behavior of cache memory.

---

**In iOS**

You only have to use

> Instruments

which are built in with Xcode I guess.

Comment: Instruments is no longer supported in iOS 10 and Xcode 8

Comment: No way..im using xcode 8.1 (8B62) and it is having instruments.

Comment: Strange, "The fact remains that Apple dropped Instruments support in Xcode 8, and Appium uses Instruments to automate the device."
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6597#issuecomment-227769375